# Apache mod_wsgi throwing error "403 Forbidden" when deploying a Django project

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have been trying to deploy a Django site using `mod_wsgi` on a CentOS server recently, but so far when I try to access the django site through my laptop, the web page has only been displaying `error: 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

In addition to reading all the obvious documentation, I have looked at these previous questions:

- [Django + mod_wsgi + Apache = 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015372/django-mod-wsgi-apache-403-forbidden)
- [Error message “Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)
- [Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)
- [Apache mod_wsgi error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807176/apache-mod-wsgi-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s)
- [Django on apache wtih mod_wsgi (Linux) - 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382666/django-on-apache-wtih-mod-wsgi-linux-403-forbidden)

Environment:

- `Centos 6.5`
- `Python 2.6`
- `Django 1.6`

I am running the following version of apache:

```
# apachectl -V  
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)  
Server built:   Apr  3 2014 23:56:16  
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25  
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9  
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9  
Architecture:   64-bit  
Server MPM:     Prefork  
threaded:     no  
forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

I installed `mod_wsgi` using Yum and have confirmed it is installed on the server:

```
# httpd -M | grep wsgi 
wsgi_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

My httpd.conf wsgi config snippet is as follows:

```
#
# Add WSGI configuration
# 

WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/basic/basic/apache/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/django/basic/
WSGIDaemonProcess ###.###.###.###
WSGIProcessGroup ###.###.###.###

<Directory /usr/local/django/basic/basic/apache>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Finally my wsgi.py script is:

```
"""
WSGI config for basic project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys

path = "/usr/local/django/basic/basic/apache"
if path not in sys.path:
     sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "basic.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Output from error log:

```
[Fri Oct 24 14:10:43 2014] [error] [client (redacted)] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /usr/local/django/basic  
[Fri Oct 24 14:11:25 2014] [error] [client (redacted)] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /usr/local/django/basic  
[Fri Oct 24 14:14:02 2014] [error] [client (redacted)] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /usr/local/django/basic
```

Notes:

- The django project is in my user's home directory but has a symbolic link in `/usr/local/django/ pointing to it
- In the past when I have worked on projects Error 403 usually meant that the permissions on a file were wrong, but I had check that and the files should all allow the apache user to access them
- My web server works fine when I comment out the wsgi related lines of the Apache config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that I posted this a bit late. This was the final fix to my apache config that ultimately worked.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /basic /var/www/django/basic/basic/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/django/basic/

<Directory /var/www/django/basic/basic>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static /var/www/django/basic/basic/static
```

And this is the final version of my wsgi.py file in python. The key line of code here was the `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE`. That variable was by default set to a directory that did not exist. I set it to `/tmp/.python-eggs` Make sure that `.python-eggs` has correct permissions for the apache user to read/write to it wherever you may place this file.

```
"""
WSGI config for basic project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys

path = "/usr/local/django/basic/basic/apache"
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp/.python-eggs'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "basic.settings")

#print os.getenv("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")
#print os.getenv("PYTHON_EGG_CACHE")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Side note:

- A friendly reminder to make sure that every file in your django application is readable, (and writeable if needed) by the apache user. Git once overwrote a file to an old permission I had set up once and it took me a little time to figure out the permissions had changed without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget set DocumentRoot. You should make the DocumentRoot can be read and  wrote by apache users.
just do like this:

```
sudo chown -R www_default:www_default /path/to/you/DocumentRoot
```

and you can also do like this :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/your/DocumentRoot
```